# Can FluentValidation recognize which methods (PUT or POST) were called?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, fluentvalidation

In `ASP.NET Core 3.0 Web API`, I'm using the same *DTO* for `Post` and `Put` methods. While creating new `Item` I want to guard against already existing name. Like this:

```
    public ItemValidator(IItemRepository itemRepository)
    {
        RuleFor(input => input.Name).NotEmpty();
        RuleFor(input => input.Name).Must(name => !itemRepository.ItemExists(name))
            .WithMessage(input => $"Item '{input.Name}' already exists");
    }
```

It all works great for update and insert. You can't update a name to name that already exists. But! When you try to change "ItemA" to "ItemA" (new name is the same as the old one) you get that error and it can be a little bit misleading (although technically correct).

In the *dto* itself, I don't have unique `id` of the item. Because I pass `id` in the path.

If I have an access to the Controller's method that has been called and its parameters (including `id`) I would be able to tell if someone is trying to change item's name to the same name.

Comment: Could you please add codes where you call `ItemValidator` as well?

Comment: @SelimYıldız You don't. FluentValidation is invoked by the Middleware upon the request. All you need to do, is to add it in Configuration, like this: `.AddFluentValidation(fv => fv.RegisterValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<ItemValidator>());`

Comment: You can get it from request route @AdamWojnar

Answer (score 9):

FluentValidation can recognize which HTTP method is called. For that, you will need to add HttpContextAccessor in the ConfigureServices method in StartUp file.

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
        services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
        services.AddMvc(setup => { }).AddFluentValidation();
        services.AddTransient<IValidator<MyModel>, MyModelValidator>();
    }
```

Now you can use IHttpContextAccessor in your validator class.
Here is my validator class

```
public class MyModelValidator : AbstractValidator<MyModel>
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
    public MyModelValidator(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;

        RuleFor(myModel => myModel.Id)
            .NotEmpty();

        RuleFor(myModel => myModel.Value)
            .Must(value => MyRule(value, _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Method));
    }

    private bool MyRule(string value, string method)
    {
        if (method.ToUpper() == "POST")
        {
            return true;
        }
        else if (method.ToUpper() == "PUT")
        {
            // validatation logic for value
            return !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value);
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

You can get Request Path from _httpContextAccessor as following

```
var path = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Path.Value;
```

**EDIT:**

Please consider marking this answer accepted if this solves your problem.